# United States Towns/States Traversing by Name Puzzle

Tags: knowledge, strategy, geography

I’m new to puzzle solving in a structured way, so please go easy on me, but I thought the following was interesting (sorry if it’s not or seems like grunt work). I came up with this while staring listlessly at a map of the U.S.:

Let's pretend that you were to start in some town in some U.S. state, say Douglas, Alaska, and then successively move to either a different town in the same state or to a different state with a town that shares that name. For example, let's say that you go from Douglas, Alaska to Douglas, Georgia to Albany, Georgia to Albany, New York. Can you come up with a route that encompasses all 50 states? What if you’re not allowed to re-enter a state once you’ve left it? Additionally. what if upon entering a state, you are forced to choose a town with a strictly different name than you entered with?

Some things I noticed while doing this:

- Hawaii seemed to be a choke point until I saw that Volcano, Hawaii can go to Volcano, California.
- Alaska and Rhode Island mostly suck.
- I originally wanted Alaska and Hawaii to be the endpoints of the journey, but now I don’t know if that’s necessary (I think Hawaii is).
- If you are allowed to jump around on one town name, this becomes much easier (I call this type of town with many states containing towns with that name hub towns).

I’m sorry if I’ve done anything wrong (oh, who am I kidding, I’ve done many things wrong), and of course feel free to correct me.

Comment: Aside: Wow is there really a Douglas *and* a Fairbanks in Alaska out of only about 42 towns?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's a list that satisfies the rule that upon entering a state, you are forced to choose a town with a strictly different name

> Ocean View, Hawaii
>  Ocean View, Delaware
>  Lincoln, Delaware
>  Lincoln, Rhode Island
>  Hope, Rhode Island
>  Hope, Alaska
>  Douglas, Alaska
>  Douglas, Wyoming
>  Dayton, Wyoming
>  Dayton, Nevada
>  Paradise Valley, Nevada
>  Paradise Valley, Arizona
>  Picacho, Arizona
>  Picacho, New Mexico
>  Clayton, New Mexico
>  Clayton, Idaho
>  Lewiston, Idaho
>  Lewiston, Utah
>  Richmond, Utah
>  Richmond, Vermont
>  Woodstock, Vermont
>  Woodstock, New Hampshire
>  Danbury, New Hampshire
>  Danbury, Connecticut
>  Chester, Connecticut
>  Chester, Montana
>  Jackson, Montana
>  Jackson, South Carolina
>  Jefferson, South Carolina
>  Jefferson, Oregon
>  Portland, Oregon
>  Portland, North Dakota
>  Colfax, North Dakota
>  Colfax, Washington
>  Manchester, Washington
>  Manchester, Maryland
>  Aberdeen, Maryland
>  Aberdeen, South Dakota
>  Bristol, South Dakota
>  Bristol, Florida
>  Venice, Florida
>  Venice, Louisiana
>  Jamestown, Louisiana
>  Jamestown, Colorado
>  Georgetown, Colorado
>  Georgetown, Mississippi
>  Liberty, Mississippi
>  Liberty, Maine
>  Princeton, Maine
>  Princeton, New Jersey
>  Florence, New Jersey
>  Florence, Massachusetts
>  Pocasset, Massachusetts
>  Pocasset, Oklahoma
>  Cherokee, Oklahoma
>  Cherokee, Alabama
>  Lafayette, Alabama
>  Lafayette, Tennessee
>  Nashville, Tennessee
>  Nashville, Arkansas
>  Salem, Arkansas
>  Salem, West Virginia
>  Athens, West Virginia
>  Athens, Georgia
>  Omaha, Georgia
>  Omaha, Nebraska
>  Aurora, Nebraska
>  Aurora, North Carolina
>  Dublin, North Carolina
>  Dublin, Virginia
>  Raven, Virginia
>  Raven, Kentucky
>  Monticello, Kentucky
>  Monticello, Wisconsin
>  Embarrass, Wisconsin
>  Embarrass, Minnesota
>  Buffalo, Minnesota
>  Buffalo, Kansas
>  Eureka, Kansas
>  Eureka, California
>  Harmony, California
>  Harmony, Indiana
>  Homer, Indiana
>  Homer, Michigan
>  Napoleon, Michigan
>  Napoleon, Missouri
>  Stockton, Missouri
>  Stockton, Iowa
>  Rome, Iowa
>  Rome, Ohio
>  Houston, Ohio
>  Houston, Texas
>  White Deer, Texas
>  White Deer, Pennsylvania
>  Rochester, Pennsylvania
>  Rochester, New York
>  Genoa, New York
>  Genoa, Illinois
>  and to get back to the start
>  Pearl City, Illinois
>  Pearl City, Hawaii

Comment: This is extremely awesome! :) +1 Question: are all the town names different in every transition?

Answer (score 7):

It so happens that

> There is a town named " Greenville" in every state in the US.  So you
>   can go to each Greenville

Comment: There are astounding 88 Washingtons in US! So some states have more than one? Confusing! There are 41 Springfields also

Comment: Is this actually true or an [urban legend](https://randomconnections.com/how-many-greenvilles/)?

Comment: In many states towns are named but not incorporated like Greenville in Oregon. I think the puzzle would be more defined if it says "City names only"

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_the_most_common_U.S._place_names only lists 31 Greenvilles.

Comment: @DEEM New Jersey has a "Washington Township" and a "Township of Washington".